# A Non-trivial example of an open cover which will cover $X^{\omega}$ but not any obvious finite sub-cover will cover the same?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I wanted to prove that $X^{\omega}$ is a compact set in product topology. $X$ is a compact space. Before entering into the Tychonoff's theorem I just wanted to examine why it is not trivial to say that product of compact spaces is compact as we did for the case of connectedness.

Can anyone please give me a non-trivial example of an open cover which will cover $X^{\omega}$ but not any obvious finite sub-cover will cover the same?

Comment: What is $X$?  In any case, I don't think this is a very fruitful question--the difficulty is not finding a finite subcover for any one specific open cover, but proving you can _always_ do it no matter what open cover you have.

Comment: I asked this question to clear my doubt. I do not post questions to make this site fruitful , rich. @EricWofsey

Comment: To show that Tychonoff's theorem is nontrivial, would it not suffice to give an example of a collection of open subsets of $X^\omega$ such that no finite subcollection covers $X^\omega$, but it's not obvious that the whole collection does not cover $X^\omega$?